# Have a script which adds Security on share to "Everyone"

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, scripting, user-permissions

**[Old post]**
*I have a shared folder on the network which is shared with "Everyone" 'Read' & 'Read & Execute' privileges.
A few people have 'Write' access and sometimes somehow when they either copy, move or save a document inside that folder the 'Everyone' security isn't included in that file.
First question would be: "Why does this happen?" followed by "Should I create a script which adds 'Everyone' to each file running like once a week?" and "How would I go about that?"
Thank you for your time.*
**[/Old Post]**

The Share in question has as Security :
Everyone : Read, List and Execute
Engineering: Read, Write, etc.

Now sometimes Engineering saves, moves or copies a file inside that share and the security for Everyone is missing. Upon executing the file it says Access Denied. I instructed tyhem to add "Everyone" to the Security tab of the File when that happens but it would be great to know why this happens.

Comment: Ah, so what you're really asking is a script which adds all permissions to 'Everyone' to a *folder*?

Comment: I believe so - I'm sorry, this is a little confusing for me. It should just add the 'Everyone' Read permission to all files in within that folder as sometimes it's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to remember when setting shared permissions for Windows. (This may or may not answer your question, but hopefully it will help)

NTFS permissions are still evaluated, but the most restrictive permission (Share vs NTFS) applies.
ex. If everyone has full control, but NTFS permissions give everyone read only access, then users only have read access over the network.

Another thing to consider, if NTFS permissions allow full control but share permissions only allow read, a user can only read over the network. However, they will have full control if accessing the files by logging into the machine.

If you're looking to set up a script that will set permissions on shares, you'll want to read this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726004.aspx#BKMK_cp

Edit:

Cacls will handle NTFS permissions, while share permissions can be set with the following:

```
NET SHARE share$=<filepath>  /GRANT:user,permission
```

Microsoft doesn't appear to have too much in terms of technet articles on the /GRANT option for net share though.

Comment: Based on your edit, you might want to look into Permission Inheritance as well. Check the NTFS permissions for the folder and see if in the advanced section under "Security", folders should be inheriting permissions. If they are not, this might explain why permissions seem to be missing from time to time.